# Problemas para fazer o ancora com jquery

Tags: html, jquery, angular, ancora

Olá,
estou fazendo uma aplicação em angular 7, e estou querendo usar ancora nos menus, como não achei nenhuma forma de fazer via typescript fiz por meio do jquery porém a ancora não funciona como esperado, quando estou no topo da página funciona tranquilamente, mas quando clico em uma ancora e após em outra ela não vai em direção a id da ancoma demarcada.
Gostaria da opinião de vocês sobre como posso resolver esse problema:

HTML:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent-333">
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto nav-flex-icons">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a onclick="rolar_para('#section1')" class="scroll nav-link waves-effect waves-light link">O Tabaco</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a onclick="rolar_para('#section2')" class="scroll nav-link waves-effect waves-light link">
       Missão e Valores
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a onclick="rolar_para('#section3')" class="scroll nav-link waves-effect waves-light link">
        Quem somos
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
function rolar_para(elemento) {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(elemento).offset().top
  }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: Olá Victor! Como vc consegue clicar em outra âncora se a tela desce e esconde o navbar ao clicar em uma?

Comment: a navbar eu deixei fixa, então se eu der scroll a navbar vai estar lá

Comment: "_mas quando clico em uma ancora e após em outra ela não vai em direção a id da ancoma demarcada_"... o que acontece? A página fica parada? Vai pra outro lugar?

Comment: Caso te interesse aqui tem uma opção só com CSS https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/380399/conflito-entre-%C3%A2ncora-e-rolagem-suave/380403#380403 (o suporte ainda não é total... mas as vezes quebra seu galho)

Comment: Coloca o html completo com a navbar fixa e as seções. Repitam comigo: exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável!

Comment: Sam, quando eu clicava no manu com ancora em que eu já estivesse clicado 1 vez, ele não ia para a ancora q eu tinha clicado, ele subia o scroll

Comment: hugocsl, o seu exemplo funcionou completamente aqui, vou testar a compatibilidade pros outros browsers